# import requests is showing error in python but it is showing in pip3 list

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, python-requests

[image: import request is not working]

If I am trying to install requests it is showing requirement already satisfied but If I am trying to import then it is throwing error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'.
```

I am running the command pip3 list then it is showing requests 2.23.0. but not 
able to import.

Comment: Can you please share complete error ?

Comment: `pythonyouareusing -m pip intall requests` then `python your_script.py` - your pip3 does not match the python you are running under.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dealing with multiple Python versions and PIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip)

Comment: Apples-MacBook-Pro:withoutrest apple$ python3 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
Apples-MacBook-Pro:withoutrest apple$ python3 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
But if I run pip3 list then it is showing requests version
Apples-MacBook-Pro: without rest apple$ pip3 list
Package    Version   
requests   2.23.0  @Shakeel

Comment: Does it now show you on which python path it failed to load ? as suggested by #modesitt  you need to install packages under python which you are using. Best practice is to create virtualenv and install your dependency over there.

Comment: Yea sure lets connect over hangout, I have sent you the invite on `sumit.sumitprakash@gmail.com`

Answer (score 0):

From the shared error link I could notice that you have two python version installed in you system and you have installed `requests` on python3.7 (i.e, `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`) and trying to `import requests` on `python3.8`

Solution: Either install `requests` on `python3.8` (I guess it should be `pip3.8 install requests`) OR run your script from `python3.7`